# protractor automaticly scroll down

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm using a protractor (5.1.2), on a Angular app (4.4.4), on chrome (62, with chromedriver_2.33).

Everytime I try a browser.get('something'), after the page is loaded, the browser seems to scroll all the vertical scrollbar to the bottom.

It is causing some issues with my tests. Some elements are not visible anymore or a table with auto loading on scrolling load more elements than expected.

I have the same issue if I try to navigate on external angular pages (as https://material.angular.io/). 
Seem working when ignoreSynchronization is active, so I supposed it's angular related.

Any idea?

Comment: That's odd, I've not heard of that being a problem before. Can you post some code so we have a better idea of the situation?
I have a specific piece of code in my tests that will scroll to the bottom of the page, but that seems like it might be the opposite of what you need.



`var lastElement = element.all(by.id('cancel')).first();
browser.actions().mouseMove(lastElement).perform();`

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it. It was axe-webdriverjs plugin, for accessibility, scrolling the whole page.